# Flutter install Dart version SDK is 1.24.3 - not Dart 2

Tags: dart, flutter

I have installed Flutter incl. Dart following [this](https://flutter.io/setup-macos/)

And to be sure that I have the latest: `flutter upgrade`

But `dart --version` shows `Dart VM version: 1.24.3 (Wed Dec 13 23:26:59 2017) on "macos_x64"`

Should that not be 2.x?

```
flutter --version
```

Output:

```
Flutter 0.4.4 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f9bb4289e9 (3 weeks ago) • 2018-05-11 21:44:54 -0700
Engine • revision 06afdfe54e
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58
```

Note: Hmm, I will just try to look for path changes...

```
where dart
```

output:

```
/usr/local/bin/dart
/usr/local/bin/dart
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your output for `flutter --version`?

Comment: Hmm, it shows Dart 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58. Just updated the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter packages its own version of dart under `<flutter_dir>/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart`. That's why you're seeing two versions.

So if you run

```
$ <flutter_dir>/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --version
```

You'll probably get something like

```
Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58 (Fri May 11 17:50:46 2018 +0000) on "linux_x64"
```